# How to randomly sample 2 indices of True values for each row in a boolean tensor in PyTorch, in the fastest way?

Tags: numpy, random, pytorch, boolean

I'm given a PyTorch boolean tensor of size `NxK` (`K>=2`), which is guaranteed to have at least 2 `True` values in each row.
For each row, I want to get the indices of 2 **random** cells with `True` values.

For example, let's say I have the following tensor:

```
tensor([[False,  True, False, False,  True],
        [ True,  True,  True, False,  True],
        [ True,  True, False,  True, False],
        [False,  True, False, False,  True],
        [False,  True, False, False,  True]])
```

So a possible output would be:

```
tensor([[1, 4],
        [4, 2],
        [0, 3],
        [4, 1],
        [4, 1]])
```

Because on the first row, we have `True` value on column 1 and 4, and on the second row we have `True` value on column 4 and 2, and so on.

Another possible output would be:

```
tensor([[4, 1],
        [1, 4],
        [0, 1],
        [1, 4],
        [1, 4]])
```

Because now a different random `True` values was selected for each row.

I've currently implemented a pytorch-numpy-pytorch solution for that, using `np.random.choice`:

```
available_trues = [t.nonzero(as_tuple=False).flatten() for t in input_tensor]
only_2_trues = [np.random.choice(t.cpu(), size=(2,), replace=False) for t in available_trues]
only_2_trues = torch.from_numpy(np.stack(only_2_trues)).cuda()
```

But this solution is not vectorized (since it works using lists) and it requires moving the data back and forth between the CPU and the GPU. Since I'm working on large matrices and running this operation many times, this causes a major slowdown.

I wonder if it can be done without list comprehension or without moving the data (or even without both :] )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Initially I was thinking if this can be done with `torch.topk` but then realized that it will be deterministic.

I was then able to make it work using `torch.multinomial` with some extra setup of a probability matrix.

Assume the matrix is `m`.

```
p = matrix / matrix.sum(axis=1).unsqueeze(1)

tensor([[0.0000, 0.5000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.5000],
        [0.2500, 0.2500, 0.2500, 0.0000, 0.2500],
        [0.3333, 0.3333, 0.0000, 0.3333, 0.0000],
        [0.0000, 0.5000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.5000],
        [0.0000, 0.5000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.5000]])
```

Then

```
p.multinomial(num_samples=2)

tensor([[4, 1],
        [2, 4],
        [1, 0],
        [1, 4],
        [1, 4]])
```

Each time you run, you get different results.

Obviously you can combine the above steps into one, I'm just showcasing what exact is the `p` matrix doing.

Comment: BTW, according to the note in the [docs](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.multinomial.html), there is no need to divide by the sum. You can use just `matrix.multinomial(num_samples=2)`

Comment: @wamitw Good to know! I guess this worked out greatly since you are working with boolean values, and it might not always be the case depending on other usecases :)